# add an audio loop to a video file with a fade out ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have two file, video.mp4 and audiotrack.mp3. I am using the following command to insert the audio with the video to create an audio track in the video, and it's working.

```
ffmpeg -y -i video.mp4 -i audiotrack.mp3 -af apad -map 0:v -map 1:a -c:v copy -shortest finalwithAudio.mp4
```

**The problem:**
The audio works fine but ends aburptly when the video reaches its end. I want it to start fading out 1 or 2 seconds before the video end. is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [afade](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#afade) filter. Assuming `video.mp4` is 10 seconds long and a fade of 1 second is wanted:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.mp3 -af "apad,afade=type=out:start_time=9:duration=1" -c:v copy -shortest output.mp4
```